# Change a string into a function/def activator

Tags: python, strings, python-3.x

```
import random


import string

# every def from 'def nothing()' to 'def wxyz()' Print out several lines of text, printing: keyword 1, call number, phone number and keyword 2
def nothing():
    print("keyword: (nothing)\ncalls: 1\n" + str(random_number()) + "\nkeyword: exit\n")

def abc():
    print("keyword: abc\ncalls: 1\n" + str(random_number()) + "\nkeyword: exit\n")

def deft():
    print("keyword: deft\ncalls: 1\n" + str(random_number()) + "\nkeyword: exit\n")

def ghi():
    print("keyword: ghi\ncalls: 1\n" + str(random_number()) + "\nkeyword: exit\n")

def jkl():
    print("keyword: jkl\ncalls: 1\n" + str(random_number()) + "\nkeyword: exit\n")

def mno():
    print("keyword: mno\ncalls: 1\n" + str(random_number()) + "\nkeyword: exit\n")

def pqrs():
    print("keyword: pqrs\ncalls: 1\n" + str(random_number()) + "\nkeyword: exit\n")

def tuv():
    print("keyword: tuv\ncalls: 1\n" + str(random_number()) + "\nkeyword: exit\n")

def wxyz():
    print("keyword: wxyz\ncalls: 1\n" + str(random_number()) + "\nkeyword: exit\n")

# keywords that are accepted and not denied
accepted_keywords = {
    0: nothing,
    1: abc,
    2: deft,
    3: ghi,
    4: jkl,
    5: mno,
    6: pqrs,
    7: tuv,
    8: wxyz
}

# creates a random phone number
def random_number():
    string = []
    x = 0
    while x != 10:
        x += 1
        number = str(random.randrange(0, 10))
        string.append(number)
    return str('(' + string[0] + string[1] + string[2] + ')' + string[3] + string[4] + string[5] + '-' + string[6] + string[7] + string[8] + string[9])

# these two things pick a random value & key from the accepted_keywords() dictionary then calls that value & key
#tester = random.randrange(len(accepted_keywords))
#accepted_keywords[tester]()

# randomizes letter so it can be aproved or denied
def random_keyword():
    keyword = ''
    chrt_count = random.choice([3,4])
    for i in range(chrt_count):
        lowercase = string.ascii_lowercase #lowercase letters
        random_letter = random.randrange(len(lowercase)) # chooses random character from var lowercase which is converted to a number based on its place in alphabet
        keyword_letter = lowercase[random_letter] # grabs the letter from lower using the number from var random_letter to located the place value of a letter
        keyword += keyword_letter
    while True:
        if keyword in accepted_keywords.values():
            print("keyword: " + keyword + "\n*Approved*\n")
            break
        else:
            print("keyword: " + keyword + "\nDenied\n")
            break

random_keyword()
```

Here is the scenario, I am using python 3.x and I am supposed use cases but since Python does not use cases, I had to use a dictionary.
My problem is that I have a function named `wxyz()` and I created another function named `random_keyword` that picks random letters from the alphabet, one at a time, and adds it into a variable named `keyword` that is a blank string. So by the time `random_keyword` has ran its course, keyword will have 3 or 4 random letters in it. For now let’s say that those random letters are “wxyz”, which is a string. Then I go through `if keyword in accepted_key: print ...`. The problem is that `keyword` is a string, therefore it does not match the `wxyz` in accepted_keywords. Is there a way to turn a string into a function/def activator?

Comment: So, this code does not work as intended? Please take a look at the [help/on-topic].

Comment: It works the way as in tended, so far, it is just that I need help understanding if there is a way to turn a string into a function/def caller (I know that is not an actual name for it but that is all I can think of).

Comment: Is this your real code? This looks more like example code than what you actually have (judging by the function names and bodies).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There are quite a lot of things you should do differently.

Let's start with your function `random_number`. You should not overwrite the `string` module (even though it is only locally), which you imported. You should also use [list comprehensions](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk) to build the string. To pretty print the number as a phone number, use [`str.format`](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-string-formatters-in-python-3). Use the fact that [`random.randrange` takes an implicit `0` as its first argument](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randrange) (just like `range`). And finally use [tuple unpacking](https://wsvincent.com/python-tuple-unpacking/), instead of manually indexing the list.

```
def random_number():
    phone_number = [random.randrange(10) for _ in range(10)]
    return "({}{}{}){}{}{}-{}{}{}".format(*phone_number)
```

---

Next, your `random_keyword` function. You can vastly simplify the building of `random_letter` by using a list comprehension again, together with [`str.join`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_join.htm), to avoid costly string addition.

Your `while True` loop also serves no purpose, since you `break` it in either case.

Also, what is the point of storing something in a dictionary (with \$\mathcal{O}(1)\$ lookup time if a key is in it) and then checking to see if something is in the values, which is a list and takes therefore \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$? At this point your dictionary is just a simple list. You can access its members with numbers from `0` to `len(accepted_keywords)`. Instead have a list of your functions and have a dictionary with their names as keys (which you can build using a dictionary comprehension).

```
functions = [nothing, abc, deft, ghi, jkl, mno, pqrs, tuv, wxyz]
accepted_keywords = {f.__name__: f for f in functions}


def random_keyword():
    keyword = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
                      for _ in range(random.choice([3, 4])))
    print("keyword: {}".format(keyword))
    print("*Approved*\n" if keyword in accepted_keywords else "Denied\n")
```

---

Finally, Python has an official style-guide, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). It recommends using `ALL_CAPS` for global constants (like `accepted_keywords`).

Python also has a `docstring` convention (written down in [PEP257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/)), which in its simplest form looks something like the following:

```
def random_number():
    """creates a random phone number"""
    ...
```

At this point you should also notice that that function name is not very descriptive, maybe something like `random_phone_number` instead?

Comment: Would you please explain how accepted_keywords = {f.__name__: f for f in functions} works? I messed with it a little bit and found if I made it accepted_keywords = {f for f in functions} it worked the same.

Comment: @HunterT. `{f.__name__: f for f in functions}` creates a dictionary where the function name is the key and the function itself the value. `{f for f in functions}` creates a set with all functions in it. The latter will always say that the keyword is not in it (because the set contains only the functions, not their names).

Comment: Please don't ansewer off-topic questions. You were even the first to VTC...

Comment: @Peilonrayz I know...I could not stop myself from answering. I later decided to close-vote because while answering it became clear to me that this is example code.

Comment: @Peilonrayz why should he not answer off topic questions?

Comment: @HunterT. It's [against site policy](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6388), and [encourages unwanted behaviour](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3650)

Comment: @Peilonrayz then where should I have posted this?

Comment: @Graipher and thank you for responding to my question, even though it was off topic.